# pixijs multiple Graphics color overlay

Tags: glsl, pixi.js

https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/discussions/9849

this is my code, I hava some questions,

```js
    app.stage.eventMode = 'static'
    app.stage.cursor = 'crosshair'
    let drawing = false

    let graphics: Graphics
    let start = { x: 0, y: 0 }
    app.stage.on("pointerdown", (event: FederatedPointerEvent) => {
        drawing = true
        start.x = event.global.x
        start.y = event.global.y
        graphics = new Graphics()
        graphics.lineStyle({
            width: 20,
            color: 0x1c32ff,
            alpha: .4,
            cap: LINE_CAP.ROUND
        })

        graphics.blendMode = BLEND_MODES.DST_ATOP
        const f2 = new Filter()
        graphics.filters = [f2]
        app.stage.addChild(graphics)
    })

    app.stage.on("pointermove", (event: FederatedPointerEvent) => {
        if (drawing) {
            graphics.moveTo(start.x, start.y)
            graphics.lineTo(event.global.x, event.global.y)
            start.x = event.global.x
            start.y = event.global.y
        }
    })
    app.stage.on("pointerup", (event: FederatedPointerEvent) => {
        drawing = false
    })
```

this is preview:
[image]

I must set both blendmode and filters,graphics.blendMode = BLEND_MODES.DST_ATOP const f2 = new Filter(), although filter is the default and does nothing,
If one of them is not set, then it will be like this
[image]

I wonder why!

I drew multiple graphics on the stage, with their alpha set to 0.4, but now their colors are superimposed.
just like the one in the picture：
[image]

I want to know how to avoid it